# Prove that $X$ is connected if and only if the only subsets of $X$ that are clopen are $X$ and $\varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove that $X$ is connected if and only if the only subsets of $X$ that are clopen are $X$ and $\emptyset$.

I know that $X$ is separated (or not connected) if $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$ and $\overline{A} \cap B = A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$ where $\overline{A}, \overline{B}$ are the closures of and $A$ and $B$ and if $X=A \cup B$. I know a set will be closed if it is not separated.

However, I'm really stuck on the proof and I don't quite know where to even begin. Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What is your definition of ‘connected’?

Comment: I guess the condition $X=A\cup B$ is missing in the cited definition of 'not connected'.

Comment: @Berci Yeah, I was missing that. I've added that into the original post. Thanks for posting that out!

Comment: @Bernard my definition of connected is not not connected, or rather not separated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your definition is false- $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, but $A=[0,1], B=[2,3]$ satisfies the condition you have. You also need $A\cup  B=X$.

Say $A\neq\emptyset$, $A\neq X$, and $A$ is clopen. Now look at $A$ and $A^C$ (complement of $A$, or $X-A$).

Now assume $X$ is separated. Using your definition, along with $A\cup B=X$, you should be able to find the answer.